# How obtain the difference from two observations from the same column in R

Tags: r, subtraction

I have a dataset with 3 different indices, and I need the difference between HPI 1 and HPI2 and the difference between HPI2 and HPI3, both for rent and sale.
The first thing that comes to my mind is to transform this DF into one with one column per HPI and then create new columns with a simple subtraction, but I don't know how to do it.
The other idea is to rest the values from the same column conditioning the operation and the date.
This is an example of the data

```
  ~Index,    ~Value, ~Operation, ~Year,
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "2017",
  "HPI2",    1.1,    "Sale", "2017",
  "HPI3",    0.89,   "Sale", "2017",
  "HPI1",    1.12,   "Rent", "2017",
  "HPI2",    0.85,   "Rent", "2017",
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "2017",
  "HPI1",  0.91,   "Sale", "2018",
  "HPI2",  1.02,   "Sale", "2018",
  "HPI3",    0.9,    "Sale", "2018",
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "2018",
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Rent", "2018",
  "HPI3",    1.12,   "Rent", "2018",)
```

I would be very thankful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Try the `lag()` or `lead()` functions from the `dplyr` library: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~Index,    ~Value, ~Operation, ~Year,
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "2017",
  "HPI2",    1.1,    "Sale", "2017",
  "HPI3",    0.89,   "Sale", "2017",
  "HPI1",    1.12,   "Rent", "2017",
  "HPI2",    0.85,   "Rent", "2017",
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "2017",
  "HPI1",  0.91,   "Sale", "2018",
  "HPI2",  1.02,   "Sale", "2018",
  "HPI3",    0.9,    "Sale", "2018",
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "2018",
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Rent", "2018",
  "HPI3",    1.12,   "Rent", "2018")

df %>%
  group_by(Year, Operation) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Index, values_from = Value) %>%
  mutate(HPI1_HPI2_diff = HPI1 - HPI2, 
         HPI2_HPI3_diff = HPI2 - HPI3)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   Year, Operation [4]
  Operation Year   HPI1  HPI2  HPI3 HPI1_HPI2_diff HPI2_HPI3_diff
  <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Sale      2017   0.9   1.1   0.89         -0.2             0.21
2 Rent      2017   1.12  0.85  1.22          0.27           -0.37
3 Sale      2018   0.91  1.02  0.9          -0.110           0.12
4 Rent      2018   1.1   0.89  1.12          0.21           -0.23
```

Comment: @ Anoushiravan. Cheers. Same idea at same time. I vote you up! I think you do not need to group at all.

Comment: @TarJae Hats off too our shared Idea! Thank you very much. I think it's the most obvious idean that comes to mind. Vote up for you too.

Comment: @TarJae Yes you are right that doesn't affect the final output.

Comment: @anoushiravanR thank you both very much!!! It was very helpful

Comment: @MagdalenaCortina my pleasure, glad it helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must reorganize your data. The `data.table` package will help you. Try this (`df` is your data):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- dcast(dt,...~Index,value.var="Value")
```

Output:

```
#    Operation Year HPI1 HPI2 HPI3
# 1:      Rent 2017 1.12 0.85 1.22
# 2:      Rent 2018 1.10 0.89 1.12
# 3:      Sale 2017 0.90 1.10 0.89
# 4:      Sale 2018 0.91 1.02 0.90
```

Then you can calculate whatever you want. Try:

```
dt <- dt %>% mutate(Col1=HPI1-HPI2, Col2=HPI2-HPI3)
```

Output:

```
#    Operation Year HPI1 HPI2 HPI3  Col1  Col2
# 1:      Rent 2017 1.12 0.85 1.22  0.27 -0.37
# 2:      Rent 2018 1.10 0.89 1.12  0.21 -0.23
# 3:      Sale 2017 0.90 1.10 0.89 -0.20  0.21
# 4:      Sale 2018 0.91 1.02 0.90 -0.11  0.12
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Transform to wide format with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` package.
2. Calculate the difference.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "Index", 
    values_from = "Value"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(diff_1v2 = HPI1 - HPI2,
         diff_1_3 = HPI2 - HPI3)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  Operation Year   HPI1  HPI2  HPI3 diff_1v2 diff_1_3
  <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Sale      2017   0.9   1.1   0.89   -0.2       0.21
2 Rent      2017   1.12  0.85  1.22    0.27     -0.37
3 Sale      2018   0.91  1.02  0.9    -0.110     0.12
4 Rent      2018   1.1   0.89  1.12    0.21     -0.23
```